# mysql dateformat from from_unixtime

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am transferring data and updating time formats.

The source data has a timestamp (stored as int(10)) and I am using the following in an attempt to convert to datetime.

```
INSERT INTO `t2`
SELECT
    t1.type,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.event_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
FROM t1;
```

when running this query the following is encountered...

```
Error detected in migrationX.sql ( Incorrect datetime value: '2014-07-06T13:00:00Z' for column 'event_date_time' at row 1 [ INSERT INTO `t2`
SELECT
    t1.type,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.event_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
FROM t1; ] )
```

Can anyone suggest a reason as to why the output would contain T and Z characters?

=================

Salient info on table structure...

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `t1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`t1_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
    `t2_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_date_time` DATETIME NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`t2_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

==================

Comment: Do you have a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger defined on `t2`?

Comment: t1.event_time contains this format, you have to check that first

Comment: Also, please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE t2`?

Comment: t1 event time - there are a few million tuples but all contain 10 digits (checked with SELECT * FROM t1 CHAR_LENGTH(event_time) = 10;) I'll add create syntax to OP

Comment: @eggyal There are no triggers involved.

Comment: Not sure from where this timezone is getting added but a quick fix would be `date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.event_time),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: @Abhik - amazingly the error persists! perhaps something else is going on...

Comment: You say that you have included the "*salient info*", but the problem is not in anything that you have shown—so it must lie in something you've stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `t2`
SELECT
    t1.type,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.event_time)
FROM t1;
```

Comment: While the default would be the format I am requesting I have defined it explicitly just for belt and braces. Unfortunately this has no effect.